# Environmental variables for Scout plugin in scout.php file

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce

I was wondering if it was possible to add .env variable for the indices area in the scout.php file?

I added this to my .env file

```
SCOUT_INDICES = "search_SCOUT_DEV"
```

Then this to my scout.php

```
\rias\scout\ScoutIndex::create('getenv(varname:’SCOUT_INDICES’)”)
```

To replace

```
\rias\scout\ScoutIndex::create('search_SCOUT')
```

Which is my Prod indices. It did not work.

Comment: Try: `\rias\scout\ScoutIndex::create(getenv('SCOUT_INDICES'))`

Comment: Thank YOU!!! That Worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use this, it should work:

```
\rias\scout\ScoutIndex::create(getenv('SCOUT_INDICES'))
```